# JxBrowser fails to register a ServiceWorker if a certificate error occurs

Tags: jxbrowser

Although this might sound right we're actually disabling certificate security errors when launching JxBrowser so the ServiceWorker should still register.
This works correctly in Firefox and Chrome.
For info this is for the ZAP HUD: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-hud
We'd love to support JxBrowser but unless this problems is fixed we wont be able to.

Comment: Did you try to disable certificate security errors in JxBrowser the same way you did in Chrome? It is hard to suggest anything specific without a sample which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Yes, and that work fine.
You should be able to reproduce this with this HUD:

```
git clone https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-hud.git
cd zap-hud
./gradlew runZap
```

that will start ZAP with the HUD enabled (you will need Java 7+)
From the Quick Start screen you can launch Firefox, Chrome and JxBrowser.
Firefox and Chrome will work fine, JxBrowser will fail logging error like the one above to the zap.log file.
If you turn off the HUD (via the button on the ZAP toolbar) then you will find that JxBrowser will be able to browse https sites while proxying through ZAP.

Comment: Ugh, sorry about the formatting ;) The instructions for running ZAP with the HUD are in the README on that repo.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not manage to launch  ZAP via the ./gradlew runZap event after Kotlin installation. Can you provide me with the list of dependencies it requires?

Comment: Oh, I thought that was it :/ What error messages did you get?

Comment: I've finally managed to launch ZAP with the HUD. However, I can't reproduce the issue from my side. With the HUD enabled, it is possible to access the site. I can see a warning and a ZAP overlay. I've used samples from https://badssl.com/ to imitate the behavior. When I disable the HUD - there is no overlay, just a warning about SSL issues on the site. Seems like correct behavior to me.

Comment: Interesting. Is this with the latest published version of JxBrowser? Re the overlay - the 'Welcome' screen doesnt imply anythings working, you need to click on the 'continue to target site' button. You should then see a set of buttons on the left and right havd side of your screen as per the gif on https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-hud If you can see those buttons then great, looks like its working for you :)   If you dont see the buttons on then its not working and you may well see an error message about failing the start the service worker.

Comment: FYI you can use any site to test this with - ZAP configures JxBrowser to proxy through it and so it will be using ZAPs local CA certificate.